# Is it possible to use an image as a bar's background color in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'd like to create a bar chart where one of the bars has an image in it and it looks like the image is revealed as the bar animates into view.

I tried creating a variable that holds an image and setting that bar's backgroundColor to that variable.

```
  var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png';
```

and in the chart config:

```
backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
          img,
          'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
          ],
```

This results in only a black bar. I'm kindof wanting to do what this is doing:
[Fill Chart.js bar chart with diagonal stripes or other patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569667/fill-chart-js-bar-chart-with-diagonal-stripes-or-other-patterns)
Only with a predefined jpg.

Comment: RTD: https://documentation.image-charts.com/chart.js/#background-image, but very importantly note that `Background image are only available with Enterprise and Enterprise+ subscriptions`

Comment: interestingly, it doesn't seem to be working in their own example.

Comment: True, which would either be due to a bug or because their demos aren't using the 'enterprise' version they mention as a requirement

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an enterprise version, Chart.js is open source.

Comment: It's available here: https://www.image-charts.com/pricing - scroll down to see the 'Advanced chart features' that the subscriptions unlock

Comment: Oh I see, Chart.js uses image-charts to function, and this is the documentation for image-charts.
Well, I'm certainly not going to pay for something that they demonstrate doesn't work correctly, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you post your attempt in a HTML/Javascript snippet? I am surprised there's an external service since Chart.JS is indeed open source and run on client browser.

Comment: The image-chart document linked by Rory above uses this:

`{ "options":{ "plugins":{ "backgroundImage":{ "url":"https://i.imgur.com/hCyint9.jpg" } } } }`

I tried putting that in my chart and got no result.

Comment: After further research, image-charts is not related to Chart.js, they simply have Chart.js compatibility within their own product.

Comment: While I don't think it completely answer your question, I managed to add a background image to all the bars. Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/yLZRQyG)

Comment: @Frixionder I think this should be the answer, your approach corresponds with the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#patterns-and-gradients); only your code doesn't always work since you don't wait for the image to load (it typically fails when someone opens the codepen for the first time with no image in the cache). So you may want to use a pattern like [this](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/RwveXMv?editors=0010) or [this one](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/gOqBVeJ?editors=0010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing my code thanks to [@kikon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16466946/kikon), the following code should answer your problem.
You can find the documentation right [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#patterns-and-gradients).

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg';

image.onload = function(){
  const fillPattern = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');

  const cfg= {
    type:'bar',
    data:{
      labels:[0,1,2,3],
      datasets:[{
        label: 'A',
        backgroundColor:['black', 'red', 'blue', fillPattern],
        data: [2,4,6,8]
      }]
    }
  }

  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```